# iOS TableView Form Navigation

Tags: ios, xcode

When using Safari and filling out a form, there are three buttons conveniently located at the top of the keyboard labeled Previous, Next, and Done. Is there a keyboard setting that can enable those or do you have to create and program these buttons manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had some success using this library:
https://github.com/simonbs/BSKeyboardControls

Answer (score 1):

There is no default property of keyboard provided in ios. You need to add toolbar for that. Then you add previous , next or done UIBarButtons in the toolbar.

When keyboard appears toolbar is also displayed above it using some animation or directly same way when it hides/disappears you have to hide the toolbar also using animations or by changing it positioning in view.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

[XCDFormInputAccessoryView](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/xcdforminputaccessoryview) is an accessory which contains the features you needed. It is easy to use. Here is how it looks with keyboard
[image]